# Administrator unable to view "Registration" pages

Tags: 7, users

[image]

If I log in as admin and want to edit the registration pages; I can not access the pages.
I can only see them if logged out but, obviously, if logged out I do not get the "edit" option.

Where do I change the viewing permissions, so that the admin can always view all pages?

Comment: What makes you think the registration page would have an "edit" tab? It's not a node, so it's not editable through the UI (unless you're using something other than the built-in registration form)

Comment: I don't think the OP understands that the edit option shows up for an admin with the correct permissions on pages, but is instead equating seeing the edit option to being in an admin viewing mode.
To edit the registration form, you either need to use an alter hook (hook_form_alter) or reorder through the manage fields part of the profiles UI.

Comment: I was able to view dpm (devel module) output on the registration page for theming and debugging by adjusting the permissions so the anonymous user can see devel output.